# UWP Ruler from InkToolbar without add InkToolbar

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, inkcanvas

Is it possible to add the Ruler from the InkToolbar without add the InkToolbar into the UI? Because I want to create an own UI Tool with Ink stuff like a little circle where I press on it and its show all the pens and more.

Greetz

Comment: For the ruler nothing exactly, because there is no API for it. The InkToolbar does not have an API where its show how to activate some tools, its a blackbox.

Comment: Why not custom the `InkToolBar` to what you want ?  You requirement is no sense to consider the `InkToolbar` but only can write a control like toolbar yourself.